# Adding static strings to a cumulative Multi-dimension array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array, ms-word

I have a REGEX loop that finds certain strings (the `Match.value` in the code below). I need to preform this loop 4 times, with 4 different REGEX's, and cumulatively build the array as it finds matches in each of the four REGEX loops.

I've been able to populate a 1D array with my matches but I cannot figure out how to add other information (all static text/strings that are associated with each match) to the other dimensions. I looking to end up with something like this:

Match.value | String1_here | String2_here | String3_here | String4_here

```
Dim serialArray() As String

For Each Match in theMatches
    Redim Preserve serialArray(x)
    serialArray(x) = Match.value
    x = x + 1
Next Match
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? What does "add other information to the other dimensions" mean?

Comment: You can only `Redim Preserve` the *last* dimension of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @SJR I need to associate other information with each match. So, for the loop associated with my first REGEX pattern, for each match it finds, I need to add some contextual information to the other dimensions. So if it finds "Cat", I need to be able to add "Animal", "Furry", and ""Black" to the cat "row" Does that make sense?

Comment: @TimWilliams I apologize, arrays are admittedly a weak spot for me. Right now, from my understanding, I have an empty 1 dimensional array. Can I change that to multi dimensional, and if so, how do I do that and add information to those other dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

```
With theMatches
    If .Count > 0 Then
        ReDim serialArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 5) 'allocate storage space for an N X 5 array
        x = 1
        For Each Match In theMatches
            serialArray(x, 1) = Match.Value
            serialArray(x, 2) = "String1"
            serialArray(x, 3) = "String2"
            serialArray(x, 4) = "String3"
            serialArray(x, 5) = "String4"
            x = x + 1
        Next Match
    End If
End With
```

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my post accordingly.  Cheers!

Comment: In addition to removing the keyword `Preserve`, I have also corrected `ReDim` so that the indexing for the array is 1-based, as I originally intended.  Please see my edit.

Comment: A more flexible solution would be nested scripting dictionaries.